# Vector push_back changes values of previous elements.

Tags: c++, stdvector

Using vector in member function getPoints() shows weird behavior.

After pushing new objects to a vector, previous objects are assigned the new value.

And when the vector is returned I get garbage values.

The vector is not storing or using reference variables.

Can someone explain what's happening.

Thank you.

## CODE

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;


class Unit{
public:
    
    double n[2];
    double &x = n[0], &y = n[1];

    Unit(double x=0, double y=0){
        n[0] = x;
        n[1] = y;
    }

    Unit& operator=(const Unit& rhs){
        this->x = rhs.x;
        this->y = rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }
    
    Unit& operator+=(const Unit& rhs){
        this->x += rhs.x;
        this->y += rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }

    Unit operator+(const Unit& rhs){
        return Unit(x+rhs.x, y+rhs.y);
    }
    
    Unit& operator-=(const Unit& rhs){
        this->x -= rhs.x;
        this->y -= rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }
    
    Unit operator-(const Unit& rhs){
        return Unit(x-rhs.x, y-rhs.y);
    }

    Unit& operator*=(const Unit& rhs){
        this->x *= rhs.x;
        this->y *= rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }

    Unit operator*(const Unit& rhs){
        return Unit(x*rhs.x, y*rhs.y);
    }

    Unit operator*=(double rhs){
        this->x *= rhs;
        this->y *= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    Unit operator*(double rhs){
        return Unit(x*rhs, y*rhs);
    }

    Unit operator/=(const Unit& rhs){
        this->x /= rhs.x;
        this->y /= rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }

    Unit operator/(const Unit& rhs){
        return Unit(x/rhs.x, y/rhs.y);
    }

    Unit operator/=(double rhs){
        this->x /= rhs;
        this->y /= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    Unit operator/(double rhs){
        return Unit(x/rhs, y/rhs);
    }
    
    double dot(const Unit& rhs){
        return x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y;
    }

    double len2(){
        return dot(*this);
    }

    double len(){
        return sqrt(len2());
    }

    double distance2(const Unit& rhs){
        Unit C = *this - rhs;
        return C.len2();
    }

    double distance(const Unit& rhs){
        return sqrt(distance2(rhs));
    }

    Unit Normalize(){ 
        return *this * 1.0 / len(); 
    }

    Unit Round(){
        return Unit(round(x), round(y));
    }

    Unit Trunc(){
        return Unit(int(x), int(y));
    }

    vector<Unit> getPoints(const Unit& rhs){
        
        vector<Unit> points;
        
        Unit start, end;
        
        if(x < rhs.x){
            
            start = *this;
            end = rhs;
        }
        else{
            
            start = rhs;
            end = *this;
        }
        
        int run = end.x - start.x;
        int rise = end.y - start.y;
        
        double m = ((double) rise) / ((double) run);
        
        double b = start.y - (m * start.y);
        
        for(int i = start.x; i < end.x; ++i){
            
            double y = (m * i) + b;
            
            int rounded = (y > 0.0) ? floor(y + .50) : ceil(y - 0.5);
            
            points.push_back(Unit(i, i));
            cout<<"Expected Output : "<< points[points.size()-1].x << " " << points[points.size()-1].y <<endl;
        }
        
        cout << endl;
        
        for (auto&p : points){
            
            cout<<"Actual Output : "<< p.x << " " << p.y << endl;
        }
        
        return points;
        
    }
};


int main()
{
    Unit a, b(10,10);
    
    auto c = a.getPoints(b);
    
    cout <<endl;
    
    for(auto& d: c){
        
        cout<<"Recieved Output : "<< d.x << " " << d.y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
Expected Output : 0 0
Expected Output : 1 1
Expected Output : 2 2
Expected Output : 3 3
Expected Output : 4 4
Expected Output : 5 5
Expected Output : 6 6
Expected Output : 7 7
Expected Output : 8 8
Expected Output : 9 9

Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9
Actual Output : 9 9

Recieved Output : 2.07386e-317 6.9151e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
Recieved Output : 6.9151e-310 6.95256e-310
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class has reference variables in it.

When you make a copy of the class via the default copy-constructor, the new object's reference variables will refer to the *same* objects that the source's references referred to. Which in this case will be member variables of the source object.

You probably intended each `Unit` 's references to refer to the members of that same `Unit`. To do this you will need to write your own copy-constructor that initializes the references appropriately. (And you should write a move-constructor too).

NB. A better approach would be to not use the reference variables at all. You could use a member function `double& x() { return n[0]; }` instead.